# external function creates class object, but main.cpp cannot call this new object?

Tags: c++, function, class, constructor, program-entry-point

I am trying to make a "monster generator" for my console game but have come across what might be a simple issue to fix, the problem is am I am somewhat new to this language.

In my main.cpp I have created a function named, `generateMonster()`:
All `generateMonster()` does is randomly generate 6 numbers which will become the attributes of this new monster.

`generateMonster()` successfully creates a monster with random attributes, but why can't I call this new Monster through main.cpp? Whenever I run my build it says:

"error: name was not declared in this scope" ---- and If I change it to `Monster::name.returnHp();` then it says "error: name is not a member of 'Monster'".  but it is, I just created 'name' with my constructor.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "Character.h"
#include "Monster.h"

using namespace std;

void generateMonster();
int main()
{
    Character Bryan = Character(1,2,5,1,10,6);
    int choice;
    while(true)
    {
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice == 1)
            {

                generateMonster();
                cout << "Monster Stats:\n\n";
                cout << "Life Points: " << name.returnHp() << endl ;
                cout << "Endurance Chance: " << name.returnEndur() << endl ;
                cout << "Dmg: " << name.returnDmg() << endl ;
                cout << "Armor: " << name.returnArmor() << endl ;
                cout << "Evasion Chance: " << name.returnEvasion() << endl ;
                cout << "Agility Chance: " << name.returnAgility() << endl ;

            }
    }



    return 0;
}

void generateMonster()
{
    int random ;
    int i, j, k, nums[50];
    srand(time(NULL)) ;
    for( i = 0; i < 50 ; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = i;
        }
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            j = (rand() % 50) ;
            k = nums[i] ; nums[i] = nums[j] ; nums[j] = k ; //switch rands
        }

    Monster name = Monster(nums[4],nums[45],nums[34],nums[21],nums[37],nums[41]);
    //creates an object(Monster class) called name with the random attributes

}
```

Monster.h

```
#ifndef MONSTER_H_INCLUDED
#define MONSTER_H_INCLUDED

class Monster
{
    private:
        float c_hp;
        float c_maxHp;
        float c_endur;
        float c_dmg;
        float c_armor;
        float c_evade;
        float c_agility;
    public:
        Monster(int hp,int endur, int dmg, int armor, int evasion, int agility); 
        //constructor
        void takeDmg(float dmg);
        float returnHp();
        float returnMaxHp();
        float returnDmg();
        float returnArmor();
        float returnEndur();
        float returnEvasion();
        float returnAgility();


 };

 #endif // MONSTER_H_INCLUDED
```

Monster.cpp

```
#include "Monster.h"
#include <iostream>

Monster::Monster(int hp,int endur,int dmg,int armor,int evasion, int agility)
 {
    c_hp = hp * 50;
    c_maxHp = hp * 50;
    c_endur = endur * 3;
    c_dmg = dmg * 2;
    c_armor = armor * 2.5;
    c_evade = evasion * 2;
    c_agility = agility * 3;
 }

 void Monster::takeDmg(float dmg)
 {
    using std::cout;
    float trueArmor,trueDmg;
    trueArmor = c_armor / 1.60;
    trueDmg = dmg - trueArmor;
       if(c_hp - trueDmg <= 0)
         {
           cout << "You have slain the creature!";
           c_hp = 0;

         }
      else
         {
           c_hp = c_hp - trueDmg;
         }
 }

 //simple return functions
 float Monster::returnHp(){return c_hp;}
 float Monster::returnMaxHp(){return c_maxHp;}
 float Monster::returnDmg(){return c_dmg;}
 float Monster::returnArmor(){return c_armor;}
 float Monster::returnEndur(){return c_endur;}
 float Monster::returnEvasion(){return c_evade;}
 float Monster::returnAgility(){return c_agility;}
```

Comment: Read about *scope*, and what are scoping rules in C++.

Comment: I see, so how do I go about solving the current situation and adjusting the scope to also include `main()`

Comment: You should try to learn some basic C++ first, then attempt a smaller problem.

Comment: Create Byran as `Character Bryan(1,2,5,1,10,6);` and mark the return functions as const `float returnHp() const;`

Comment: The problem is you need to return the monster from your function somehow.

Comment: You realize you are not helping the issue @juanchopanza, Bart already told me to learn about scope. But an answer to this is exactly what I was looking for **before** I posted my question and I couldn't find it anywhere on this site. Obvious to me now, because instead of answering questions(providing examples, etc) and actually being helpful you just tell someone to go study.

Comment: And I am telling you to learn basic C++ because if you don't know about scope, it is likely you don't know about other basic concepts and you'll be back here asking about some trivial problem tomorrow. But if you prefer to learn one SO question at a time, that's your choice. It will just take a *very* long time.

Comment: also, `main` should return `int` - replace `void main()` using `int main()`.

Comment: I do **Know** about scope, I did not know scope extended to constructors for a class since classes tend to be part of the entire file. Telling someone to "go study" is not constructive at all, it's better just not to say anything, obviously if I know about classes and such, I have studied on my own accord, but even if you study you miss things.

Comment: `"scope extended to constructors for a class since classes tend to be part of the entire file"` this doesn't make sense. A variable of class type has the same scope rules as a variable of int or float type.

Comment: @user3743533 You go as I (and others here) have suggested - **read** about scope... This time you got a spoon-fed solution, but as juanchopanza said: it will save you (and us) lots of time if you'll actually try to learn C++ first, and do this in **small steps** with a **book/tutorial** instead.

Comment: You want to save time? Simply don't respond or ignore the question, no one is pinning you on your chair and forcing you to answer my question or discuss learning techniques with me. Besides that, this issue was not only about scope, but also about returning the current object from that function as Neil had mentioned. This is me learning c++, I spent some time online searching for the answer and could not find anything, my book also has not mentioned it from what I read **so far**, but I like to take on bigger challenges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` does not exist in `main`. It only exists inside the `generateMonster` function. To generate a Monster that can be used in `main`, simply return it from the function. Change the return type to `Monster`, and add a return statement.

```
Monster generateMonster()
{
    ... Everything your function is currently doing ...

    // plus this
    return name;
}
```

Then, in main, you can do this:

```
Monster m = generateMonster();
```

Comment: ...and of course use `m` instead of `name`, or do `Monster name = generateMonster();` to minimize needed changes in code.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: Yeah, I avoided using the same name in order to make it clear that the name of the object in main did not have to be the same as the name of the object being returned.

Comment: Thanks, this also taught me something else.